# $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin(a+xi)=?$ where $a$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have a question regarding how to solve this limit:
 $\lim_{x\to \infty } \sin(a+xi)$, where $a$ is constant. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: the complex equivalent of $\infty$.

Long answer:

The identity $\sin \left( a+ix\right) = \sin a \cosh x + i\cos a \sinh x$ implies that the limit's real and imaginary parts can't both be finite, since the hyperbolic functions diverge and $\sin^2 a +\cos^2 a=1$ ensures at least one of the circular trigonometric functions of $a$ is nonzero. For extended real numbers we distinguish between $+\infty$ and $-\infty$, but an attempt to define "extended complex numbers" could allow them to be infinite in any direction. In general one cannot define the "phase" of such a result, so we simply augment $\mathbb{C}$ with a single point at infinity.